# Only allow access to a file if logged in to the CMS [SilverStripe]

Tags: php, silverstripe

When a user creates a booking via this website, an invoice (pdf) will be generated and saved in assets/invoices. Only staff members will access these to download and email to the clients. However, at the moment if the exact URL is known by somebody they are able to access it whether they are logged in or not. I am trying to restrict access to these files for those logged into the CMS only. Is there a way to do that via some permissions module?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: I have removed the code, but I can explain. I tried through the htaccess file to limit access to an IP address (thinking those in the CMS would get the server IP), however they did not and it returned there personal IP so this option did not work. That's all I have tried so far, i've looked around online for a solution but I can't seem to find anyone who has the same problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is Secure Assets the module your after: https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-secureassets

With it you can set permission for Files/Folders "that mirrors the access restrictions of sitetree pages".

Comment: There is a old and a rewriten version. The new version should work just fine with SSTR ~3.1 and Apache.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to achieve this through modules I was not getting any results. What I did to achieve this was adding a private folder in the assets directory, having all my secure files within this folder. I added a htaccess file within the private folder containing:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !cookie_name=cookie_value; [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /page-not-found [NC,L]
```

This code checks for a specific cookie name and a specific cookie value, if this condition is not met it will redirect the user to the page-not-found url.

Within an extension to a booking system in the CMS I had present, I set the cookie. This cookie was then set upon logging into the CMS, if a user did not have this cookie they could not view any of the files/folders within the /assets/private directory.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a module a while back to do this. https://github.com/colymba/ss-privateassets

You could try it or use it to write your own.